# How to take the trace of a csr matrix

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, networkx

I am using networkx in python and the command

```
A = nx.adjacency_matrix(G)
```

returns a csr matrix, not a 2D array. Hence, when I try to do

```
np.trace(A)
```

I get an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/numpy/core/fromnumeric.py", line 1279, in trace
    return asarray(a).trace(offset, axis1, axis2, dtype, out)
ValueError: diag requires an array of at least two dimensions
```

How can I get around to take the trace?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use a matrix. `networkx` has the [`nodes_with_selfloops`](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/development/reference/generated/networkx.DiGraph.nodes_with_selfloops.html#networkx.DiGraph.nodes_with_selfloops) method to list nodes with a self-loop:

```
>>> import networkx
>>> G = networkx.Graph()
>>> G.add_node(1)
>>> G.add_node(2)
>>> G.add_node(3)
>>> G.add_edge(2, 2)
>>> G.add_edge(1, 3)
>>> G.nodes_with_selfloops()
[2]
```

If you graph is not weighted, the trace would just be the number of items in the list, so you can do:

```
>>> len(G.nodes_with_selfloops())
1
```

If it is weighted, you can sum the weight of each of the self-loops:

```
>>> import networkx
>>> G = networkx.Graph()
>>> G.add_node(1)
>>> G.add_node(2)
>>> G.add_node(3)
>>> G.add_edge(1, 1, weight=2)
>>> G.add_edge(2, 2, weight=1.5)
>>> sum(G.get_edge_data(node, node)['weight'] for node in G.nodes_with_selfloops())
3.5
```

Comment: Well, I skipped some things on my question. I first raise the matrix to the third power and then I want the diagonal. This is because I want to count the number of triangles, so if $A$ is the adjacency matrix, then Tr(A^3) would give me the number of triangles of $G$ (times 3).

Comment: `networkx` also has a function to compute triangles: https://networkx.github.io/documentation/networkx-1.9/reference/generated/networkx.algorithms.cluster.triangles.html

Comment: Does that work for multigraphs? Meaning if I have two edges from 1 to 2, one from 2 to 3 and one from 3 to 1, I would like to count that graph as having two triangles.

Comment: line 67, in _triangles_and_degree_iter
    raise NetworkXError("Not defined for multigraphs.")

Answer (score 10):

```
In [543]: A=np.arange(9).reshape(3,3)
```

For an array, `trace` can be called as function or method.  In fact, `np.trace` delegates the action to `A.trace`.

```
In [544]: np.trace(A)
Out[544]: 12

In [545]: A.trace()
Out[545]: 12

In [546]: M=sparse.csr_matrix(A)
```

In general calling a numpy function on a sparse matrix does not work - unless the matrix has a matching method.

```
In [547]: np.trace(M)
...
ValueError: diag requires an array of at least two dimensions

In [548]: M.trace()
...
AttributeError: trace not found
```

But a sparse matrix has a `diagonal` method, which is just as good:

```
In [549]: M.diagonal()
Out[549]: array([0, 4, 8], dtype=int32)

In [550]: M.diagonal().sum()
Out[550]: 12
```

Of course you could have turned the sparse matrix into an array first:

```
In [551]: np.trace(M.A)
Out[551]: 12
```